# sigma algebra created by partition

Tags: measure-theory

So there is a countable (disjoint) partition of $\Omega = \bigcup_{i \in \mathbb{N}}B_i$ and now I'm interested in the $\sigma$-algebra created by this partition $\sigma(\{B_i:i\in\mathbb{N}\})$.
I've been wondering whether this is just the Powerset $\mathcal{P(\Omega)}$, because all singletons are available, but then I remembered the Vitali set.

There is supposed to be an explicit form, but I really don't know where to start here. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the collection of all possible unions of the $B_i$'s (i.e. sets of the form $\bigcup_{i \in I} B_i$ where $I $ is some subset of $\{1,2,3...\}$). This class contains each $B_i$ and it is  a sigma algebra: closure under countable unions is obvious. The complement of a union of the $B_i$'s is the union of the remaining $B_j$'s. It now follows that the sigma algebra generated by the partition  is containes in this collection. The reverse inclusion is obvious.